# Why am I geting the no match operator error code

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, min, string-length

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    const int SZ = 5;
    string word[SZ];
    int len,min,large,max;
    for(int i = 0; i < SZ; i++){
         cout << "Please Enter a word five times: ";
         cin >> word[i];
    }
    min = word[SZ].length();
   for(int i = 0; i < SZ; i++){
        if(word[i] < len){ // I'm getting it on this line of code
            min = word[i];
        }
   }


    return 0;
}
```

My code is not properly running and currently I'm trying to find the smallest word of 5 different words inputted by the user.

Comment: Please show the exact error you are getting

Comment: what do think `min = words[SZ].length()` do?

Comment: `word[i]` is a `string` and `len` is an `int` - so what exactly do you expect `word[i] < len`to do?

Comment: `word[i]` is a string. You're comparing it to an int.

Comment: why do you compare `words[]` with `words[].length()` ? Do you have enabled warning on your compiler ?

Comment: `min = word[SZ].length();` the array index is out of bounds; Your program will have undefined behaviour, if you keep this line.

Answer (score 0):

There are some mitakes in your code:

- Your first `cout` should be above the `for` loop rather than inside of it.
- `word[SZ].length()` is accessing a string that is out of bounds of the array.  You should be accessing the 1st string at `word[0]` instead.
- on the statement `if(word[i] < len)`, `len` is uninitialized. For that matter, you don't even need `len` at all, use `min` instead. But more importantly, you are comparing a `string` to an `int`, which is why you are getting an error.  You need to compare the string's `length()` value instead.

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    const int SZ = 5;
    string word[SZ];
    int min, max;

    cout << "Please enter " << SZ << " words: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < SZ; i++){
         cin >> word[i];
    }

    min = max = word[0].length();

    for(int i = 1; i < SZ; i++){
        if (word[i].length() < min){
            min = word[i].length();
        }
        if (word[i].length() > max){
            max = word[i].length();
        }
    }

    cout << "min: " << min << ", max: " << max << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/93vnYY)

Answer (score 0):

For starters, this (modified) statement:

```
 cout << "Please Enter " << SZ << " words: ";
```

should be placed before the `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < SZ; i++){
     cin >> word[i];
}
```

In this statement:

```
min = word[SZ].length();
```

you are using a non-existent element of the array with the index `SZ`, while the valid range of indices for the array is `[0, SZ)`.

So, rewrite it like:

```
auto min = word[0].length();
```

Within the `for` loop, this statement:

```
if(word[i] < len)
```

does not make sense. You need to write:

```
if(word[i].length() < min)
```

Also, this statement:

```
min = word[i];
```

has invalid operands for the assignment operator.

The loop can look like

```
auto min = word[0].length();
for( size_t i = 1; i < SZ; i++ ){
    if( word[i].length() < min ){ 
        min = word[i].length();
    }
}
```

If you need to find the word with the minimal length then the for loop can look the following way

```
size_t min = 0;
for( size_t i = 1; i < SZ; i++ ){
    if( word[i].length() < word[min].length() ){ 
        min = i;
    }
}
```

Pay attention to that, there is a standard algorithm `std::min_element` declared in the header `<algorithm>` that can be used instead of the manually written loop.

Comment: "*there is a standard algorithm `std::min_element()`*" - There is also `std::minmax_element()` for finding the smallest and largest elements at the same time